# Unit Testing Spring Security With Weblogic Container

Tags: spring-security, weblogic

I am attempting to unit test Spring Security with a weblogic 10.3.5 container. I have been provided an environment with Eclipse and Weblogic, neither of which I am overly familiar with.

Upon startup, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    blahblahblah
```

As a result, this unit test fails:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetByIdViaAccessRoles() {
        Person result;

      // Test the results with a ROLE_ADMIN user. This SHOULD work.
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(admin);
    result = personRepository.getById(1L);
    assertNotNull(result);

    // test the results with a ROLE_USER. Should also be good...
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);
    result = personRepository.getById(1L);
    assertNotNull(result);

    // test the results with a nonexistent user. Should go kablooie.
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(nonuser);
    try {
        result = personRepository.getById(1L);
        fail("Should be impossible to get this with a nonexistent user.");
    } catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {

    }
}
```

So, I'm guessing that I'm not picking up servlet.jar from weblogic. But since I'm a relatively new eclipse user (IntelliJ for a long time), I'm not sure I've got weblogic set up correctly.

In my project facets, I have Oracle WebLogic Web App Extensions checked, but no other weblogic ones are configured. Dynamic Web Modules is also checked.

Can anyone offer assistance to a relative newb?

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard. Somewhere I found another option for target runtimes. Once I set it, it worked.